# Mails from website with 2-step verification in Gmail

Tags: php, email, curl, gmail, email-verification

In my website I use gmail to send mails. I use Pear mail in the frontend and cURL in the backend.

I have two mail accounts managed by gmail: one is a gmail account and the other has my own domain but is managed by Google Apps.

I can send emails from my website with 2-step verification using my gmail account and app specific passwords. But I cannot do the same with the other account. **Why?**

With both accounts I can send email without 2-step verification, and with my-own-domain account I can send emails with 2-step verification using the K-9 Mail Android app and the gmail app specific password.

Comment: Have you tried using "app specific passwords" to log in?

Comment: I tried. I have edited the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

Look here, have you tried to enable IMAP and POP in the gmail of your Google Apps ?: https://support.google.com/a/answer/105694?hl=en